# How to update the value of a prop upon a state change in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent React component (MainComponent) that renders a child component (theKeyComponent) and passes a constant as a prop (myID). The parent component also tracks the state 'activeLink'.

```
import theKeyComponent from "../components/theKeyComponent.jsx";

export default class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     activeLink: '#section1'
    }
  }
  render(){
   const myId = this.state.activeLink === '#section1' ? '0001' : '0002';
   return(){
     <theKeyComponent myID={myID} />
     <otherComponent otherPropsHere={otherProps} />
   }
  }
}
```

Here's a bit from inside the KeyComponent

```
export default class HelpScoutBeacon extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    myID: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    myAPImethod('init', this.props.myID);
  } 
  render(){return(){}}
}
```

I want to change the value of the constant myID depending on the value of 'activeLink'. This is not a problem when both components are mounted for the first time. However, when the value of 'activeLink' changes 'myID' doesn't change since the child component is already mounted.

I'm struggling to see what would be the 'React way' of doing this. Should 'myID' be set as another state and the function that sets the state for activeLink should include another one to set the state of myID? Or is this overcomplicating things and there's an easier way to re-render only that particular child component so that it considers the new value of myID.

I'm new to React so I was hoping I could get some clarification form SO community.

Comment: where do you set the new state of activeLink?

Comment: In that same MainComponent

Comment: so the myID prop on theKeyComponent does not reflect the myID constant set on your MainComponent render? can you show a little bit more code pertaining to theKeyComponent

Comment: Exactly the myID prop on the KeyComponent only reflects the value of myID initially but trying to change the value when activeLink changes. The setState function for activeLink is defined in MainComponent but triggered in otherComponent. 
There's nothing of importance in the KeyComponent it only received the prop.myID and uses it to initialise an object from an API I'm using. I'll edit the question to add a bit of it

Comment: The react way is to simply implement the `componentDidUpdate` (or `useEffect` with `myId` dependency in functional components) to "react" to the prop updating. Please include the code of the component consuming `myId` that isn't updating.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. I've included the component that uses myId now for you to see. I was under the impression that the componentDidUpdate method should be in the MainComponent and would be updating myKeyComponent every time something changed in that parent component, which was concerning to me. I'll check back the documentation for that method and consider including it in the child component. That's what you are suggesting, right?

Comment: Yes, implement it in any component needing to react to props and/or state updating.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 Thanks for your help. You were right the issue was that I was missing to re-initialise the object form the API I'm using. I'm now executing the re-initialisation function in the componentDidUpdate method after a conditional that checks if myID has changed or not so to re-initialise only when needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is not a problem when both components are mounted for the first
> time. However, when the value of 'activeLink' changes 'myID' doesn't
> change since the child component is already mounted.

The issue is with regards to how you handle the trigger of the API call.
`componentDidMount` will only trigger when the component was initially mounted. This will not be triggered if a state is updated. You are going to want to use `componentDidUpdate` React Lifecycle as well in augmentation to `componentDidMount`. `componentDidUpdate` will trigger when your activeLink state changes because you pass it as props to `theKeyComponent`

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    myAPImethod('init', this.props.myID);
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Of course that make sense 95faf8e76605e973 thanks for that. I'll try it now and see if it works

Comment: I've tried the componentDidUpdate method I see it works as you suggested. The issue I found is that the object from the API that I'm initialising causes problems when doing so sequentially. I guess I'd need to find a way to do this only when the state of activeLink changes and not when any update happens. Will have a look to the useEffect method.

Comment: @alopez02 Normally you need to compare previous state/props to current state/props *then* take some action. If you blindly do things without the comparison it can lead to bad behavior. At least with the `useEffect` you can limit when the effect callback is triggered using the dependency array.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 make sense. I'll give it a second look. Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

```
import theKeyComponent from "../components/theKeyComponent.jsx";

export default class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     activeLink: '#section1'
    }
  }

 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.activeLink !== state.activeLink ) {
      // updating the state here if there are any changes in props.
      return {
        activeLink: props.activeLink,
      };
    }

    // Return null if the props hasn't changed
    return null;
    }
```

use getDerivedStateFromProps hook to find out changes of props. you need to update the changes of props in state.

```
 render(){
  // now, here your state is updated. 
   const myId = this.state.activeLink === '#section1' ? '0001' : '0002';
   return (
     <theKeyComponent myID={myID} />
     <otherComponent otherPropsHere={otherProps} />
   )
  }
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: thanks Azizul let me digest this. I'm not sure I've explained the problem clearly so this solution may not be what I'm looking after. In my case I'm trying to listen for changes in the state 'activeLink' and react to them by changing the value of a prop.
Perhaps you are talking about the same problem, I'll have a look at the getDerivedStateFromProps hook and see if it make sense

Comment: Let me know, where you are changing the props. so that I can help you in a proper way. answer updated, have a look  @alopez02

Comment: where exactly is the function getDerivedStateFromProps supposed to be placed in the code?

Comment: just to let you know that the issue, as pointed out by 95faf8e76605e973  was more to do with the API method I was using inside the keyComponent rather than a React issue. React was indeed re-rendering the component when the value of activeLink changed but I was not considering that along with that change I had to re-initialize the API object. I've done that now inside a componentDidUpdate method in the keyComponent and it's working OK. Thanks anyway for your help.